# Array pointer data being cleared in between function calls without an explicit command?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I have the following issue:

In a C++ program I have a global data structure declared as `Renderer Rendering_Handler`, which contains a member field defined as `vector<Render_Info> visble objects`.

What the data structures themselves are doing is not important, they are wrappers needed to abstract data to parallelize my program.

To be clear, Rendering_Handler is completely global, and it's in fact a singleton (I can 100% confirm that the constructor has been called once and only once for this class).

I have declared the following class method:

```
Render_Info* Renderer::add_Render_Info()
{
    visible_objects.push_back(Render_Info());
    return &(visible_objects.back());
}
```

Simple enough, it creates a new `Render_Info` structure, appends it to the `visible_objects` array and returns a pointer to the object.

A different data structure called `Chunk` has a constructor defined as

```
Chunk::Chunk(vec3 offset, World* w) 
{
    /*initialize some values*/

    draw_info = Rendering_Handler->add_Render_Info();
    draw_info->VBOs = vector<GLuint>(5);

    /*initialize OpenGL VAOs, VBOs and other buffer objects*/

    cout << draw_info->VBOs.size() << endl;
    cout << draw_info << endl;
}
```

It also has a method defined as:

```
void Chunk::update_render_info()
{
    cout << draw_info->VBOs.size() << endl;
    cout << draw_info << endl;

    /*OpenGL stuff*/

}
```

And finally

We have the method that initializes everything:

```
World::World()
{   
    /*Initialize chunks in a circular 3D array*/
    loaded_chunks = new Chunk_Holder(h_radius, h_radius, v_radius, this);

    for(int i=0; i<h_radius; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<h_radius; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<v_radius; k++)
            {
               (*loaded_chunks)(i,j,k)->update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the rpgram is:

[image]

...

[image]

Let's focus on the frist 2 and last 2 lines of the output, which correspond to the print statements I have added for debugging.

The first 2 lines indicate that 5 elements have been added to the buffer at location 0x556edb7ae200

The last 2 lines tell me that the same buffer (same since the memory location is the same) now contains 0 elements.

As you can see from the snaps of the code, no function is called in between creating the Chunks and updating them. Does anybody have an idea of what could be causing the dissapearance of these elements?

Have I not correctly reserved the memory? Are these objects being cleared without my knowledge due to wrong allocation?

Comment: `visible_objects.push_back()` call may invalidate all pointers to elements of `visible_objects`, leaving all your `draw_info`pointers dangling.

Comment: OHHHH shoot, you mean, it will re-allocate the memory if it goes above the previous allocated limit, thus moving every single pointer to a new spot?

Comment: Given code bits do not produce any output at all and you never reserve any memory (which will help preventing pointer invalidation) either.

Comment: They do produce output look at the cout << statemets, and memory is allocated implicetly through the use of vectors, I think the guy above you nailed the issue

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you should consider adding this as an answer.

Comment: How many items do you have in that list? Perhaps it would make more sense to make it a list of pointers (`std::vector<Render_Info*> visible_objects`) and allocate `Render_Info` on the heap (`visible_objects.push_back(new Render_Info());`).

Comment: Correct. Elements in a `std::vector` get stored in a continuous area of memory. `std::vector` uses some algorithms to heuristically reserve the chunk of memory in advance, with some room to spare, and newly added elements to the `std::vector` grow it until all previously reserved memory has been allocated, and the next allocation moves/copies the entire vector into a larger block. That's how `std::vector` works. Any pointers to elements in the vector may not be valid when the vector grows next. If you need stable pointers, don't use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're storing pointers to elements in vector and at the same time you keep calling [`vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) which every now and then has to resize the vector and move all elements to new memory chunk. This will invalidate all the pointers you have obtained before.

To give you more context: `vector` stores its elements in a continuous chunk of memory. When `vector::push_back` is called and there's no free space left in this chunk of memory then `vector` will allocate another chunk of memory with twice the size of the old chunk. Then it will copy/move all the elements from old chunk to the new one. Finally the old chunk will be destroyed. When you call `&(visible_objects.back())` you will get an address in memory that's inside current memory chunk owned by `visible_objects`. If later `visible_objects.push_back` is called and `visible_objects` has to migrate to new bigger memory chunk then all the addresses obtained before will be stale as they point to the old chunk of memory that has been destroyed.